# GridView OnItemClickListener in Adapter

Tags: java, android, gridview

Как втиснуть `OnItemClickListener` в Adapter, чтобы уже в зависимости от выбранной позиции совершать действия.

Вот код:

```
public class AdapterParameters extends BaseAdapter {
    private LayoutInflater inflater;
    private Activity activity;
    private List<Item> items;
    ImageLoader imageLoader = AppController.getmInstance().getmImageLoader();
    public AdapterParameters(Activity activity,List<Item> items){
        this.activity = activity;
        this.items = items;
    }
    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return items.size();
    }

    @Override
    public Object getItem(int position) {
        return items.get(position);
    }

    @Override
    public long getItemId(int position) {
        return position;
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        if(inflater == null){
            inflater = (LayoutInflater) activity.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        }
        if(convertView == null){
            convertView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.item_parameters,null);
        }
        if(imageLoader == null)
            imageLoader = AppController.getmInstance().getmImageLoader();
        NetworkImageView imageView = (NetworkImageView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.networkImageView_cart);
        TextView title = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.textView_item_name);

        //GridView gvParameters = (GridView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.GridView_Parameters);
        gvParameters.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {

            }
        }); ////////////////////////////////////////////////////////

        //getting data for row
        Item item = items.get(position);
        title.setText(item.getTitle());
        imageView.setImageUrl(item.getImage(), imageLoader);

        return convertView;
    }
```

Comment: Зачем он вам именно в адаптере? Что-то неладное вы задумали, похоже.

Comment: gvParameters.setOnItemClickListener перенесите в код фрагмента/активити, где лежит gridview

Answer (score 1, accepted):

попробуйте так

```
@Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

    //........

    convertView.setOnClickListener(......)  // у вас есть доступ к position и по нему  будете получать конкретный елемент списка 
    return convertView;
    }
```

Comment: спасибо. работает